# Swift: shortcut unwrapping of array of optionals

Tags: swift

Assume we have an array of optionals defined:

```
var arrayOfOptionals: [String?] = ["Seems", "like", "an", nil, "of", "optionals"]
```

I can force unwrap it in a short way: `var arrayForCrash = arrayOfOptionals.map { $0! }`

But that will make app to crash, is there any other short way(without explicitly unwrapping) how I can unwrap an array of optional?

Comment: @Antonio ["If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: removing my comments above - they are irrelevant now. @Hurden, I apologize again

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This solution will get you a new array with all values unwrapped and all nil's filtered away.

Swift 4.1:

```
let arrayOfOptionals: [String?] = ["Seems", "like", "an", nil, "of", "optionals"]
let arrayWithNoOptionals = arrayOfOptionals.compactMap { $0 }
```

Swift 2.0:

```
let arrayOfOptionals: [String?] = ["Seems", "like", "an", nil, "of", "optionals"]
let arrayWithNoOptionals = arrayOfOptionals.flatMap { $0 }
```

Swift 1.0:

```
let arrayOfOptionals: [String?] = ["Seems", "like", "an", nil, "of", "optionals"]
let arrayWithNoOptionals = arrayOfOptionals.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far. Also it'll return an array of `[String]`

Comment: This works only with Swift 2, which as of today is still in beta.

Comment: In Swift 4.1, `flatMap` (for the purpose of unwrapping optionals) has been renamed to `compactMap`.

Answer (score 9):

Since it is an array of optionals, it is possible some of the entries are `nil`.  Instead of *force unwrapping* with `!`, use the *nil coalescing operator* to turns `nil`s into empty strings.

```
let arrayOfOptionals: [String?] = ["This", "array", nil, "has", "some", "nils", nil]

let array:[String] = arrayOfOptionals.map{ $0 ?? "" }
// array is now ["This", "array", "", "has", "some", "nils", ""]
```

Comment: unrelated to question. you should know an empty alternative in your Element type.

Answer (score 3):

Although you can use `flatMap { $0 }` to remove nils, flatMap is actually a much more powerful function, and has an overloaded version which does something completely different (e.g. flatten `[[Int]]` to `[Int]`). If you're not careful, you may accidentally invoke the wrong function.

I would recommend using an extension on SequenceType to remove nils. If you use [`removeNils()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38548106/35690), you'll be able to essentially do the following:

```
[1, nil, 2].removeNils() == [1, 2]
```

It works by making `Optional` conform to an `OptionalType` protocol which allows extending `SequenceType`s that contain `Optional` values.

For more information see the [original answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38548106/35690).

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

Easy to read and safe approach to filter nils of any sequence

```
protocol OptionalProtocol {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var optional: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalProtocol {
    var optional: Wrapped? {
        return self
    }
}

extension Sequence where Element: OptionalProtocol {
    var removingOptionals: [Element.Wrapped] {
        return self.compactMap { $0.optional }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let array: [Int?] = [1, 2, nil, 3, 4, nil]
print(array.removingOptionals) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4], has type [Int]
```

Answer (score 1):

I took @Cenny's answer and decided to make an operator out of it:

```
prefix operator <!> {}

prefix func <!> <T>(array: [T?]) -> [T] {
  return array.filter{ $0 != nil }.map{ $0! }
}
```

I'm using it to parse an array of JSON objects and filter the ones that failed:

```
static func parse(j: JSONArray) -> [Agency]? {
  return <!>j.map { self.parse($0) }
}
```

**Update for Swift 2+:**

Use `flatMap` operator and it'll only return non-nil objects

Answer (score 1):

The more interesting, how to unwrap an optional array of optional values. It is important to deal when we are working with JSON, because JSON can potentially contain `null` value for an array of something.

Example:

```js
{ "list": null }
// or
{ "list": [null, "hello"] }
```

To fill a Swift struct we may have a model:

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    var list: [String?]?
}
```

And to avoid working with `String??` as a first item we could:

```
var myStruct = try! JSONDecoder.init().decode(MyStruct.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
let firstItem: String? = s1.list?.compactMap { $0 }.first
```

With `compactMap { $0 }` we can avoid

```
let i2: String?? = s1.list?.first
```

`compactMap { $0 }` is an equivalent of `filter { $0 != nil }. map { $0! }`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import Foundation

var test: [String!] = ["this","is","a",nil,"test"]
for string in test {
    if string != nil {
        print(string)
    }
}
```

Output is `thisisatest`.

---

In your case use `[String!]`, if I understood you correctly.