# Creating an extension to filter nils from an Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift-extensions

I'm trying to write an extension to Array which will allow an array of optional T's to be transformed into an array of non-optional T's.

e.g. this could be written as a free function like this:

```
func removeAllNils(array: [T?]) -> [T] {
    return array
        .filter({ $0 != nil })   // remove nils, still a [T?]
        .map({ $0! })            // convert each element from a T? to a T
}
```

But, I can't get this to work as an extension. I'm trying to tell the compiler that the extension only applies to Arrays of optional values. This is what I have so far:

```
extension Array {
    func filterNils<U, T: Optional<U>>() -> [U] {
        return filter({ $0 != nil }).map({ $0! })
    }
}
```

(it doesn't compile!)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's not possible to restrict the type defined for a generic struct or class - the array is designed to work with any type, so you cannot add a method that works for a subset of types. Type constraints can only be specified when declaring the generic type

The only way to achieve what you need is by creating either a global function or a static method - in the latter case:

```
extension Array {
    static func filterNils(_ array: [Element?]) -> [Element] {
        return array.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
    }
}

var array:[Int?] = [1, nil, 2, 3, nil]

Array.filterNils(array)
```

Or simply use `compactMap` (previously `flatMap`), which can be used to remove all nil values:

```
[1, 2, nil, 4].compactMap { $0 } // Returns [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Fair enough, now that I think about it that makes sense - I was just thinking that it would make that particular method only available to Optional types, but of course it would try to apply to all of them. So I guess I'll be doing what you suggested then, or creating a free function outside of the Array class!

Comment: .flatMap does exactly the same, but you don't need to write an extension. You really should update your answer to reflect that.

Comment: From swift 4, flatMap is deprecated. We can use `compactMap` instead of `flatMap`

Comment: @Antonio I ended up making this: `func filterNils<T>() -> [T] where Element == T? {
      self.compactMap { $0 }
   }`

Answer (score 80):

As of Swift 2.0, you don't need to write your own extension to filter nil values from an Array, you can use `flatMap`, which flattens the Array and filters nils:

```
let optionals : [String?] = ["a", "b", nil, "d"]
let nonOptionals = optionals.flatMap{$0}
print(nonOptionals)
```

Prints:

```
[a, b, d]
```

## Note:

There are 2 `flatMap` functions:

- One `flatMap` is used to remove non-nil values which is shown above. Refer - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907182-flatmap
- The other `flatMap` is  used to concatenate results. Refer - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap

Comment: The only bad thing (minor) is it's Complexity: O(M + N) instead of O(N). Looks like internally `flatMap` is a "conjunction" of `map` and `filter` instead of  slightly faster 1-loop own implementation. But for this question it's not a problem

Comment: @zxcat What's M and N?

Comment: @kostek, here is a quote from `flatMap` implementation: - Complexity: O(*M* + *N*), where *M* is the length of `self` and *N* is the length of the result.

Comment: Although flatMap can be used most of the time, it's actually a much more powerful function which can lead to unintended consequences. I would recommend using [removeNils](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38548106/35690) instead.

Comment: There are 2 flatMap functions (overloaded), one is to return concatenated results and the other is to return non-nil values. Refer - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907182-flatmap

Answer (score 64):

TL;DR

**Swift 4**

Use `array.compactMap { $0 }`. Apple updated the framework so that it'll no longer cause bugs/confusion.

**Swift 3**

To avoid potential bugs/confusion, don't use `array.flatMap { $0 }` to remove nils; use an extension method such as `array.removeNils()` instead (implementation below, **updated for Swift 3.0**).

---

Although `array.flatMap { $0 }` works most of the time, there are several reasons to favor an `array.removeNils()` extension:

- `removeNils` **describes exactly what you want to do**: remove `nil` values. Someone not familiar with `flatMap` would need to look it up, and, when they do look it up, if they pay close attention, they'll come to the same conclusion as my next point;
- `flatMap` has two different implementations which do **two entirely different things**. Based off of type-checking, **the compiler is going to decide** which one is invoked. This can be very problematic in Swift, since type-inference is used heavily. (E.g. to determine the actual type of a variable, you may need to inspect multiple files.) A refactor could cause your app to invoke the wrong version of `flatMap` which could lead to **difficult-to-find bugs**.
- Since there are two completely different functions, it makes understanding `flatMap` much more difficult since you can **[easily conflate the two](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-flatmap/)**.
- `flatMap` can be called on non-optional arrays (e.g. `[Int]`), so if you refactor an array from `[Int?]` to `[Int]` you may **accidentally leave behind `flatMap { $0 }` calls** which the compiler won't warn you about. At best it'll simply return itself, at worst it'll cause the other implementation to be executed, potentially leading to bugs.
- In Swift 3, if you don't explicitly cast the return type, **the compiler will choose the wrong version**, which causes unintended consequences. (See Swift 3 section below)
- Finally, it **slows down the compiler** because the type-checking system needs to determine which of the overloaded functions to call.

---

To recap, there are two versions of the function in question both, unfortunately, named `flatMap`.

1. Flatten sequences by removing a nesting level (e.g. `[[1, 2], [3]] -> [1, 2, 3]`)

   ```
   public struct Array<Element> : RandomAccessCollection, MutableCollection {
       /// Returns an array containing the concatenated results of calling the
       /// given transformation with each element of this sequence.
       ///
       /// Use this method to receive a single-level collection when your
       /// transformation produces a sequence or collection for each element.
       ///
       /// In this example, note the difference in the result of using `map` and
       /// `flatMap` with a transformation that returns an array.
       ///
       ///     let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
       ///
       ///     let mapped = numbers.map { Array(count: $0, repeatedValue: $0) }
       ///     // [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
       ///
       ///     let flatMapped = numbers.flatMap { Array(count: $0, repeatedValue: $0) }
       ///     // [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
       ///
       /// In fact, `s.flatMap(transform)`  is equivalent to
       /// `Array(s.map(transform).joined())`.
       ///
       /// - Parameter transform: A closure that accepts an element of this
       ///   sequence as its argument and returns a sequence or collection.
       /// - Returns: The resulting flattened array.
       ///
       /// - Complexity: O(*m* + *n*), where *m* is the length of this sequence
       ///   and *n* is the length of the result.
       /// - SeeAlso: `joined()`, `map(_:)`
       public func flatMap<SegmentOfResult : Sequence>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Iterator.Element]
   }
   ```
2. Remove elements from a sequence (e.g. `[1, nil, 3] -> [1, 3]`)

   ```
   public struct Array<Element> : RandomAccessCollection, MutableCollection {
       /// Returns an array containing the non-`nil` results of calling the given
       /// transformation with each element of this sequence.
       ///
       /// Use this method to receive an array of nonoptional values when your
       /// transformation produces an optional value.
       ///
       /// In this example, note the difference in the result of using `map` and
       /// `flatMap` with a transformation that returns an optional `Int` value.
       ///
       ///     let possibleNumbers = ["1", "2", "three", "///4///", "5"]
       ///
       ///     let mapped: [Int?] = numbers.map { str in Int(str) }
       ///     // [1, 2, nil, nil, 5]
       ///
       ///     let flatMapped: [Int] = numbers.flatMap { str in Int(str) }
       ///     // [1, 2, 5]
       ///
       /// - Parameter transform: A closure that accepts an element of this
       ///   sequence as its argument and returns an optional value.
       /// - Returns: An array of the non-`nil` results of calling `transform`
       ///   with each element of the sequence.
       ///
       /// - Complexity: O(*m* + *n*), where *m* is the length of this sequence
       ///   and *n* is the length of the result.
       public func flatMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
   }
   ```

#2 is the one that people use to remove nils by passing `{ $0 }` as `transform`. This works since the method performs a map, then filters out all `nil` elements.

You may be wondering **"Why did Apple not rename #2 to `removeNils()`"?** One thing to keep in mind is that using `flatMap` to remove nils is not the only usage of #2. In fact, since both versions take in a `transform` function, they can be much more powerful than those examples above.

For example, #1 could easily split an array of strings into individual characters (flatten) and capitalize each letter (map):

```
["abc", "d"].flatMap { $0.uppercaseString.characters } == ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

While number #2 could easily remove all even numbers (flatten) and multiply each number by `-1` (map):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].flatMap { ($0 % 2 == 0) ? nil : -$0 } == [-1, -3, -5]
```

(Note that this last example can cause Xcode 7.3 to spin for a very long time because there are no explicit types stated. Further proof as to why the methods should have different names.)

The real danger of blindly using `flatMap { $0 }` to remove `nil`s comes not when you call it on `[1, 2]`, but rather when you call it on something like `[[1], [2]]`. In the former case, it'll call invocation #2 harmlessly and return `[1, 2]`. In the latter case, you may think it would do the same (harmlessly return `[[1], [2]]` since there are no `nil` values), but it will actually return `[1, 2]` since it's using invocation #1.

The fact that `flatMap { $0 }` is used to remove `nil`s seems to be more of Swift [community](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26854528/35690) [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870365/how-to-use-swift-flatmap-to-filter-out-optionals-from-an-array) rather than one coming from Apple. Perhaps if Apple notices this trend, they'll eventually provide a `removeNils()` function or something similar.

Until then, we're left with coming up with our own solution.

---

## Solution

```
// Updated for Swift 3.0
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    func map<U>(_ f: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: OptionalType {
    func removeNils() -> [Iterator.Element.Wrapped] {
        var result: [Iterator.Element.Wrapped] = []
        for element in self {
            if let element = element.map({ $0 }) {
                result.append(element)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

(Note: Don't get confused with `element.map`... it has nothing to do with the `flatMap` discussed in this post. It's using [`Optional`'s `map` function](http://blog.xebia.com/the-power-of-map-and-flatmap-of-swift-optionals/) to get an optional type that can be unwrapped. If you omit this part, you'll get this syntax error: "error: initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Self.Generator.Element'." For more information about how `map()` helps us, see [this answer I wrote about adding an extension method on SequenceType to count non-nils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38582199/35690).)

#### Usage

```
let a: [Int?] = [1, nil, 3]
a.removeNils() == [1, 3]
```

#### Example

```
var myArray: [Int?] = [1, nil, 2]
assert(myArray.flatMap { $0 } == [1, 2], "Flat map works great when it's acting on an array of optionals.")
assert(myArray.removeNils() == [1, 2])

var myOtherArray: [Int] = [1, 2]
assert(myOtherArray.flatMap { $0 } == [1, 2], "However, it can still be invoked on non-optional arrays.")
assert(myOtherArray.removeNils() == [1, 2]) // syntax error: type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'OptionalType'

var myBenignArray: [[Int]?] = [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
assert(myBenignArray.flatMap { $0 } == [[1], [2, 3], [4]], "Which can be dangerous when used on nested SequenceTypes such as arrays.")
assert(myBenignArray.removeNils() == [[1], [2, 3], [4]])

var myDangerousArray: [[Int]] = [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
assert(myDangerousArray.flatMap { $0 } == [1, 2, 3, 4], "If you forget a single '?' from the type, you'll get a completely different function invocation.")
assert(myDangerousArray.removeNils() == [[1], [2, 3], [4]]) // syntax error: type '[Int]' does not conform to protocol 'OptionalType'
```

(Notice how on the last one, flatMap returns `[1, 2, 3, 4]` while removeNils() would have been expected to return `[[1], [2, 3], [4]]`.)

---

The solution is similar to the [answer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/12078) @fabb linked to.

However, I made a few modifications:

- I didn't name the method `flatten`, since there is already a `flatten` method for sequence types, and giving the same name to entirely different methods is what got us in this mess in the first place. Not to mention that it's much easier to misinterpret what `flatten` does than it is `removeNils`.
- Rather than creating a new type `T` on `OptionalType`, it uses the same name that `Optional` uses (`Wrapped`).
- Instead of [performing `map{}.filter{}.map{}`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/974fe589fed9d87f6417ce9d83aad767dde45aaa/stdlib/public/core/FlatMap.swift), which leads to `O(M + N)` time, I loop through the array once.
- Instead of using `flatMap` to go from `Generator.Element` to `Generator.Element.Wrapped?`, I use `map`. There's no need to return `nil` values inside the `map` function, so `map` will suffice. By avoiding the `flatMap` function, it's harder to conflate yet another (i.e. 3rd) method with the same name which has an entirely different function.

The one drawback to using `removeNils` vs. `flatMap` is that the type-checker may need a bit more hinting:

```
[1, nil, 3].flatMap { $0 } // works
[1, nil, 3].removeNils() // syntax error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context

// but it's not all bad, since flatMap can have similar problems when a variable is used:
let a = [1, nil, 3] // syntax error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
a.flatMap { $0 }
a.removeNils()
```

---

I haven't looked into it much, but it seems you can add:

```
extension SequenceType {
  func removeNils() -> Self {
    return self
  }
}
```

if you want to be able to call the method on arrays that contain non-optional elements. This could make a massive rename (e.g. `flatMap { $0 }` -> `removeNils()`) easier.

---

## Assigning to self is different than assigning to a new variable?!

Take a look at the following code:

```
var a: [String?] = [nil, nil]

var b = a.flatMap{$0}
b // == []

a = a.flatMap{$0}
a // == [nil, nil]
```

Surprisingly, `a = a.flatMap { $0 }` does not remove nils when you assign it to `a`, but it *does* remove nils when you assign it to `b`! My guess is that this has something to do with the overloaded `flatMap` and Swift choosing the one we didn't mean to use.

You could temporarily resolve the problem by casting it to the expected type:

```
a = a.flatMap { $0 } as [String]
a // == []
```

But this can be easy to forget. Instead, I would recommend using the `removeNils()` method above.

---

## Update

Seems like there's a proposal to deprecate at least one of the (3) overloads of `flatMap`: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md

Comment: I highly disagree with the part `Will lead to bugs`. Yeah sure it is undefined behavior when you suddenly change `[Int?]` to `[Int]`... but as you mentioned type-inference will detects types automatically... The ONLY case that this will be a bug, is where `.flatMap` is the last line of your code (like your unit-tests) which means, it was not needed to begin with. because you will use it's result somewhere! in UI, bind to some other variable, return from a method... and compiler will catch that error there...

Comment: But i do agree this part was really confusing: `a = a.flatMap{$0}
a // == [nil, nil]`

Comment: The reason why `a` remains `[nil, nil]`, is because `a` is still of type `[Int?]`. In which `nils` are valid.

Comment: This solution does no longer work in Swift 4, I have not yet got it to work. Any clue?

Comment: There's an accepted proposal for Swift 5: [`compactMap`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md) to remove nils from an array of optionals. It also references a new `Sequence.compact()` but I can't find the proposal for that

Comment: Consider putting your solution code nearer the top of your answer.

Answer (score 12):

Since Swift 2.0 it is possible to add a method that works for a subset of types by using `where` clauses. As discussed in this [Apple Forum Thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/12078) this can be used to filter out `nil` values of an array. Credits go to @nnnnnnnn and @SteveMcQwark.

As `where` clauses do not yet support generics (like `Optional<T>`), a workaround is necessary via a Protocol.

```
protocol OptionalType {  
    typealias T  
    func intoOptional() -> T?  
}  

extension Optional : OptionalType {  
    func intoOptional() -> T? {  
        return self.flatMap {$0}  
    }  
}  

extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: OptionalType {  
    func flatten() -> [Generator.Element.T] {  
        return self.map { $0.intoOptional() }  
            .filter { $0 != nil }  
            .map { $0! }  
    }  
}  

let mixed: [AnyObject?] = [1, "", nil, 3, nil, 4]  
let nonnils = mixed.flatten()    // 1, "", 3, 4
```

Comment: With the final version of Swift, the anser of @Chris Trevarthen is much more simple. The only plus this solution has, is that `flatten` cannot be called on an array that already does not contain any optionals.

Comment: ...and that it's more elegant to write just `flatten()` than `flatMap{$0}`... but I agree that it's a bit too much code just for this... btw why you don't use `flatMap` in the extension instead of `filter` and `map`?

Comment: As far as I remember, flatMap was added to Optionals only after 2.0, my answer is older than that

Comment: Actually it isn't that much code considering that `OptionalType` is also useful for other things, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138712/function-arrayoptionalt-optionalarrayt this is preferable over writing `flatMap{$0}` each time.

Answer (score 12):

## Swift 4

If you are fortunate enough to be using Swift 4 then you can filter out nil values using `compactMap`

`array = array.compactMap { $0 }`

E.g.

```
let array = [1, 2, nil, 4]
let nonNilArray = array.compactMap { $0 }

print(nonNilArray)
// [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Answer (score 6):

## Swift 4

This works with Swift 4:

```
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var optional: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {
    var optional: Wrapped? { return self }
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: OptionalType {
    func removeNils() -> [Iterator.Element.Wrapped] {
        return self.flatMap { $0.optional }
    }
}
```

### Test:

```
class UtilitiesTests: XCTestCase {
    
    func testRemoveNils() {
        let optionalString: String? = nil
        let strings: [String?] = ["Foo", optionalString, "Bar", optionalString, "Baz"]
        XCTAssert(strings.count == 5)
        XCTAssert(strings.removeNils().count == 3)
        let integers: [Int?] = [2, nil, 4, nil, nil, 5]
        XCTAssert(integers.count == 6)
        XCTAssert(integers.removeNils().count == 3)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution for Swift 5.3 and beyond

```
extension Array where Element == Any? {
   /**
    * Remove optionals from array
    * ## Examples:
    * Array.filterNils([2,nil,1,0]) // [2,1,0]
    * let someArr: [Int?] = [2,nil,1,0]
    * Array.filterNils(someArr) // [2,1,0]
    */
   static func filterNils<T>(_ array: [T?]) -> [T] {
      return array.compactMap { $0 }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to define `where Element == Any?` if the function is static anyways?

Comment: Good question. I think it was non-static. And then I moved to static and didn't change the clause.