# How to use swift flatMap to filter out optionals from an array

Tags: swift, functional-programming, option-type, higher-order-functions, flatmap

I'm a little confused around flatMap (added to Swift 1.2)

Say I have an array of some optional type e.g.

```
let possibles:[Int?] = [nil, 1, 2, 3, nil, nil, 4, 5]
```

In Swift 1.1 I'd do a filter followed by a map like this:

```
let filtermap = possibles.filter({ return $0 != nil }).map({ return $0! })
// filtermap = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I've been trying to do this using flatMap a couple ways:

```
var flatmap1 = possibles.flatMap({
    return $0 == nil ? [] : [$0!]
})
```

and

```
var flatmap2:[Int] = possibles.flatMap({
    if let exercise = $0 { return [exercise] }
    return []
})
```

I prefer the last approach (because I don't have to do a forced unwrap `$0!`... I'm terrified for these and avoid them at all costs) except that I need to specify the Array type.

Is there an alternative away that figures out the type by context, but doesn't have the forced unwrap?

Comment: You probably meant Swift 1.2 vs 1.1, there is no Swift 1.3 yet (or did I miss something?)

Comment: Opps, yes think I had Xcode 6.3 on my mind... updated question - thanks!

Comment: Although you *can* use `flatMap { $0 }` to remove nils, the real question is *should* you. If you're not careful, `flatMap` can lead to bugs, so I recommend using [removeNils](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38548106/35690) instead.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since **Swift 4.1** you can use compactMap:

```
let possibles:[Int?] = [nil, 1, 2, 3, nil, nil, 4, 5]
let actuals = possibles.compactMap { $0 }
```

(Swift 4.1 replaced some overloads of flatMap with compactmap.
If you are interested in more detail on this then see for example:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/replacing-flatmap-with-compactmap/
)

With **Swift 2** b1, you can simply do

```
let possibles:[Int?] = [nil, 1, 2, 3, nil, nil, 4, 5]
let actuals = possibles.flatMap { $0 }
```

For earlier versions, you can shim this with the following extension:

```
extension Array {
    func flatMap<U>(transform: Element -> U?) -> [U] {
        var result = [U]()
        result.reserveCapacity(self.count)
        for item in map(transform) {
            if let item = item {
                result.append(item)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

One caveat (which is also true for Swift 2) is that you might need to explicitly type the return value of the transform:

```
let actuals = ["a", "1"].flatMap { str -> Int? in
    if let int = str.toInt() {
        return int
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
assert(actuals == [1])
```

For more info, see http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/07/23/changes-to-the-swift-standard-library-in-2-0-betas-2-5/

Comment: I saw flatMap but didn't know you could use it to filter optionals like that. Really nice addition to Swift 2!

Answer (score 15):

I still like the first solution, which creates only one intermediate
array. It can slightly more compact be written as

```
let filtermap = possibles.filter({ $0 != nil }).map({ $0! })
```

---

But `flatMap()` without type annotation and without forced
unwrapping is possible:

```
var flatmap3 = possibles.flatMap {
    flatMap($0, { [$0] }) ?? []
}
```

The outer `flatMap` is the array method

```
func flatMap<U>(transform: @noescape (T) -> [U]) -> [U]
```

and the inner `flatMap` is the function

```
func flatMap<T, U>(x: T?, f: @noescape (T) -> U?) -> U?
```

---

Here is a simple performance comparison (compiled in Release mode).
It shows that the first method is faster, approximately by a factor
of 10:

```
let count = 1000000
let possibles : [Int?] = map(0 ..< count) { $0 % 2 == 0 ? $0 : nil }

let s1 = NSDate()
let result1 = possibles.filter({ $0 != nil }).map({ $0! })
let e1 = NSDate()
println(e1.timeIntervalSinceDate(s1))
// 0.0169369578361511

let s2 = NSDate()
var result2 = possibles.flatMap {
    flatMap($0, { [$0] }) ?? []
}
let e2 = NSDate()
println(e2.timeIntervalSinceDate(s2))
// 0.117663979530334
```

Comment: Thanks! Given that the filter/map option is faster I might stick with it since (for me) it's clearest what's happening.

Comment: in swift 2 you can also simply go `possibles.flatmap{ $0 }`. See docs: `public func flatMap<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T?) rethrows -> [T]`  Flatmap returns an `Array` containing the non-nil results of mapping `transform` over `self`.

Comment: @DanielGalasko: Yes, that's what Fizker writes in the (now) accepted answer. I think that wasn't available when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Related to the question. If you are applying `flatMap` to an optional array, do not forget to optionally or force unwrap your array otherwise it will call `flatMap` on `Optional` and not objects conforming to `Sequence` protocol. I made that mistake once, E.g. when you want to remove empty strings:

```
var texts: [String]? = ["one", "two", "", "three"] // has unwanted empty string

let notFlatMapped = texts.flatMap({ $0.count > 0 ? $0 : nil })
// ["one", "two", "", "three"], not what we want - calls flatMap on Optional

let flatMapped = texts?.flatMap({ $0.count > 0 ? $0 : nil })
// ["one", "two", "three"], that's what we want, calls flatMap on Array
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce`:

```
let flattened = possibles.reduce([Int]()) { 
        if let x = $1 { return $0 + [x] } else { return $0 } 
    }
```

You are still kind of declaring the type, but it's slightly less obtrusive.

Comment: That's clever use of reduce, but (for me) takes too much mental unwrapping to see what's happening. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is something I seem to end up doing quite a lot I'm exploring a generic function to do this.

I tried to add an extension to Array so I could do something like `possibles.unwraped` but couldn't figure out how to make an extension on an Array. Instead used a custom operator -- hardest part here was trying to figure out which operator to choose. In the end I chose `>!` to show that the array is being filtered `>` and then unwrapped `!`.

```
let possibles:[Int?] = [nil, 1, 2, 3, nil, nil, 4, 5]

postfix operator >! {}

postfix func >! <T>(array: Array<T?>) -> Array<T> {
    return array.filter({ $0 != nil }).map({ $0! })
}

possibles>!
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```