# Checking for nil Value in Swift Dictionary Extension

Tags: swift, dictionary, null, extension-methods, option-type

I have the following code in a playground file:

```
extension Dictionary {

    func test()  {

        for key in self.keys {
            self[key]
        }
    }
}

var dict: [String: AnyObject?] = [
    "test": nil
]

dict.test()
```

I will henceforth refer to the line within the for-each loop as the output since it is what's relevant.  In this particular instance the output is `nil`.

When I change the for-each loop to look like this:

```
for key in self.keys {
    print(self[key])
}
```

The output is `"Optional(nil)\n"`.

What I really want to do is check the value for nil, but the code:

```
for key in self.keys {
    self[key] == nil
}
```

outputs `false`.

One other thing I tried was the following:

```
for key in self.keys {
    self[key] as! AnyObject? == nil
}
```

which produces the error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>' to 'Swift.AnyObject'
```

Any help with this is much appreciated!

Comment: This is shaping up as a very good question but could you please go back and say (1) what you are _trying_ to do and (2) what is _actually_ happening?

Comment: Here is an example that demonstrates how to check "double optionals" in a dictionary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225232/two-or-more-optionals-in-swift, and how to distinguish between "value for key does not exist" and "value for key exists and is nil".

Answer (score 8):

You've gotten yourself into kind a mess, because a dictionary whose values can be `nil` presents you with the prospect of a *double-wrapped Optional*, and therefore two kinds of `nil`. There is the `nil` that you get if the key is missing, and then the `nil` that you get if the key is *not* missing and you unwrap the fetched result. And unfortunately, you're testing in a playground, which is a poor venue for exploring the distinction.

To see what I mean, consider just the following:

```
var d : [String:Int?] = ["Matt":1]
let val = d["Matt"]
```

What is the type of `val`? It's `Int??` - an Int wrapped in an Optional wrapped in another Optional. That's because the value *inside* the dictionary was, by definition, an Int wrapped in an Optional, and then fetching the value by its key wraps that in *another* Optional.

So now let's go a bit further and do it this way:

```
var d : [String:Int?] = ["Matt":nil]
let val = d["Matt"]
```

What is `val`? Well, the playground may *say* it is `nil`, but the truth is more complicated; it's `nil` *wrapped in another Optional*. That is easiest to see if you *print* `val`, in which case you get, not `nil`, but `"Optional(nil)"`.

But if we try for something where the key isn't there at all, we get a *different answer*:

```
let val2 = d["Alex"]
```

That really *is* `nil`, signifying that the key is missing. And if we *print* `val2`, we get `"nil"`. The playground fails to make the distinction (it says `nil` for both `val` and `val2`), but converting to a String (which is what `print` does) shows the difference.

So part of the problem is this whole double-wrapped Optional thing, and the other part is that the Playground represents a double-wrapped Optional in a very misleading way.

**MORAL 1**: A dictionary whose value type is an Optional can get really tricky.

**MORAL 2**: Playgrounds are the work of the devil. Avoid them. Use a real app, and use logging to the console, or the variables pane of the debugger, to see what's really happening.

Comment: Very fine article about exactly this, and suggestions for doing something about it, at Apple's site: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=12

Answer (score 3):

Checking if a dictionary value is `nil` makes sense only if the 
dictionary values are an `Optional` type, which means that you have to
restrict your extension method to that case.

This is possible by defining a protocol that all optional types conform
to (compare [How can I write a function that will unwrap a generic property in swift assuming it is an optional type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563161/how-can-i-write-a-function-that-will-unwrap-a-generic-property-in-swift-assuming/34575096#34575096), which is just a slight modification of [Creating an extension to filter nils from an Array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190631/creating-an-extension-to-filter-nils-from-an-array-in-swift/30892122#30892122)):

```
protocol OptionalType {  
    typealias Wrapped 
    var asOptional : Wrapped? { get }
}  

extension Optional : OptionalType {  
    var asOptional : Wrapped? {  
        return self 
    }  
}
```

Now you can define an extension method with is restricted to 
dictionaries of optional value types:

```
extension Dictionary where Value : OptionalType {

    func test()  {
        for key in self.keys { ... }
    }
}
```

As Matt already explained, `self[key]` can only be `nil` if that key
is missing in the dictionary, and that can not happen here. So you 
can always retrieve the value for that key

```
            let value = self[key]!
```

inside that loop. Better, enumerate over keys and values:

```
        for (key, value) in self { ... }
```

Now `value` is the dictionary value (for `key`), and its type 
conforms to `OptionalType`. Using the `asOptional` protocol property
you get an optional which can be tested against nil:

```
             if value.asOptional == nil { ... }
```

or used with optional binding.

Putting all that together:

```
extension Dictionary where Value : OptionalType {

    func test()  {
        for (key, value) in self {
            if let unwrappedValue = value.asOptional {
                print("Unwrapped value for '\(key)' is '\(unwrappedValue)'")
            } else {
                print("Value for '\(key)' is nil")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var dict: [String: AnyObject?] = [
    "foo" : "bar",
    "test": nil
]

dict.test()
```

Output:

```
Value for 'test' is nil
Unwrapped value for 'foo' is 'bar'
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `asOptional` property is doing?  Is it simply wrapping `self` as an optional again?  I tested by creating a new variable as `AnyObject?` and assigned `"a"` to it.  I printed the variable out as-is and using `asOptional` and got the same result for both.

Comment: @Alex311: Yes, it returns the value itself, but as `Wrapped?` so that the compiler can treat it as an optional. It is a "trick" or "workaround" (going back to https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/12078) because you cannot define something like `extension Dictionary where Value : Optional<T>`.