# Unwrapping generic type

Tags: swift, swift3

Let's say I have some variable with type

```
let someVariable: SomeType<AnotherType?>
```

and I am sure that this concrete instance not contain any `nil` of `AnotherType?`. Is there is general way to convert it to `SomeType<AnotherType>`? For example, I need this convert for use `someVariable` in some function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563161/how-can-i-write-a-function-that-will-unwrap-a-generic-property-in-swift-assuming

Comment: @BenjaminLowry disagree. Question that you link is about `SequenceType`  and about removing `nil` cases. In my question there is no `nil` cases and general type.

Comment: `SomeType<T?>` and `SomeType<T>` are different and unrelated types. Without concrete information (such as how an instance of SomeType can be created) this might be difficult to answer.

Comment: And what does it mean that *"that this concrete instance not contain any nil of AnotherType?"* ? From the given declaration it is not clear if `AnotherType?` is the type of some property in `SomeType`.

Comment: @MartinR I trying to imagine general case, when I don't know much about `SomeType`. Your tips was helpful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It could go along these lines:

```
protocol _Optional {
    associatedtype _Wrapped
    func unveil() -> _Wrapped?
}

extension Optional: _Optional {
    typealias _Wrapped = Wrapped
    func unveil() -> _Wrapped? { return self }
}

extension SomeType where T: _Optional {
    func rewrap() -> SomeType<T._Wrapped>? {
        guard let _value = value.unveil() else { return nil }
        return SomeType<T._Wrapped>(value: _value)
    }
}

struct SomeType<T> {
    let value: T
}

let someValue = SomeType<Int?>(value: 42)       // SomeType<Int?>
let rewrappedValue = someValue.rewrap()         // SomeType<Int>?
let forceUnwrappedValue = someValue.rewrap()!   // SomeType<Int>
```

Specifics depend on details of the particular implementation for `SomeType` (I use a simplest assumption in my example).