# Swift: Extension on [<SomeType<T>?] to produce [<T>?] possible?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, option-type, swift-extensions

**In Swift, I have a custom struct with this basic premise:**

A wrapper struct that can contain any type that conforms to `BinaryInteger` such as Int, UInt8, Int16, etc.

```
protocol SomeTypeProtocol {
    associatedtype NumberType

    var value: NumberType { get set }
}

struct SomeType<T: BinaryInteger>: SomeTypeProtocol {
    typealias NumberType = T

    var value: NumberType
}
```

And an extension on Collection:

```
extension Collection where Element: SomeTypeProtocol {
    var values: [Element.NumberType] {
        return self.map { $0.value }
    }
}
```

For example, this works nicely:

```
let arr = [SomeType(value: 123), SomeType(value: 456)]

// this produces [123, 456] of type [Int] since literals are Int by default
arr.values
```

**What I would like to do is the exact same thing, but for `SomeType<T>?`**

```
let arr: [SomeType<Int>?] = [SomeType(value: 123), SomeType(value: 456)]

// this doesn't work, obviously
arr.values

// but what I want is this:
arr.values // to produce [Optional(123), Optional(456)]
```

I've tried numerous attempts to solve this and a fair amount of research, but I'm hoping any of the sage Swift veterans might shed some light on this.

This is what I envision it might look like, but this doesn't work:

```
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<T>> {
    var values: [T?] {
        return self.map { $0?.value }
    }
}
```

**This is a clumsy way of achieving the goal without using generics, and it works:**

```
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<Int>> {
    var values: [Int?] {
        return self.map { $0?.value }
    }
}

let arr: [SomeType<Int>?] = [SomeType(value: 123), SomeType(value: 456)]
arr.values // [Optional(123), Optional(456)]
```

But it requires manually writing extensions for every known type conforming to BinaryInteger, and will not automatically include possible future types adopting BinaryInteger without manually updating the code.

```
// "..." would contain the var values code from above, copy-and-pasted
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<Int>> { ... }
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<Int8>> { ... }
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<UInt8>> { ... }
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<Int16>> { ... }
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<UInt16>> { ... }
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<Int32>> { ... }
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<UInt32>> { ... }
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<Int64>> { ... }
extension Collection where Element == Optional<SomeType<UInt64>> { ... }
```

## EDIT 2018-Jun-23:

### Solution #1 - Fully Generic but Must be Func, Not Computed Property

Expanded on [Ole's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51001112/2805570):

Pros: If `values()` becomes a `func` and not a computed property, this is an elegant solution.

Cons: No known way to implement this approach as computed properties, and Swift's Quick Help popup shows [T] and [T?] when inspecting `values()` in your code. ie: it just says `func values<T>() -> [T] where T : BinaryInteger` which isn't very informative or Swifty. However it still remains strongly typed of course.

```
extension Collection {
    func values<T>() -> [T] where Element == SomeType<T> {
        return map { $0.value }
    }

    func values<T>() -> [T?] where Element == SomeType<T>? {
        return map { $0?.value }
    }
}
```

### Solution #2 - Optional Protocol Workaround

Expanded on [Martin's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50999846/2805570):

Pros: Allows use of computed properties (cleaner for the end-user to access since it doesn't require func parens) and shows inferred type in Xcode's Quick Help popup.

Cons: Not as elegant from an internal code standpoint, as it requires a workaround. But not necessarily a drawback.

```
// Define OptionalType

protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var asOptional: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {
    var asOptional: Wrapped? {
        return self
    }
}

// Extend Collection

extension Collection where Element: SomeTypeProtocol {
    var values: [Element.NumberType] {
        return self.map { $0.value }
    }
}

extension Collection where Element: OptionalType, Element.Wrapped: SomeTypeProtocol {
    var values: [Element.Wrapped.NumberType?] {
        return self.map { $0.asOptional?.value }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there is a simpler solution now, but you can use the same “trick” as in [How can I write a function that will unwrap a generic property in swift assuming it is an optional type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563161/how-can-i-write-a-function-that-will-unwrap-a-generic-property-in-swift-assuming/34575096#34575096) and [Creating an extension to filter nils from an Array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190631/creating-an-extension-to-filter-nils-from-an-array-in-swift/30892122#30892122), the idea goes back to [this Apple Forum Thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/12078).

First define a protocol to which all optionals conform:

```
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var asOptional: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional : OptionalType {  
    var asOptional: Wrapped? {  
        return self 
    }  
}
```

Now the desired extension can be defined as

```
extension Collection where Element: OptionalType, Element.Wrapped: SomeTypeProtocol {
    var values: [Element.Wrapped.NumberType?] {
        return self.map( { $0.asOptional?.value })
    }
}
```

and that works as expected:

```
let arr = [SomeType(value: 123), nil, SomeType(value: 456)]
let v = arr.values

print(v) // [Optional(123), Optional(456)]
print(type(of: v)) // Array<Optional<Int>>
```

Comment: Thank you - this is my preferred solution since it allows use of computed properties. (See my edit in my original post for a fully realized implementation. I opted to change the protocol name to `OptionalType_ForSomeType` to avoid potential namespace collisions with other code or libraries that may coincidentally use the same protocol name - which may not be necessary, but I like to be overly cautious.)

Answer (score 9):

[Martin R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50999846) is a good solution. An alternative that doesn't require an extra marker protocol is this: write an *unconstrained* extension on `Collection`, and in that extension, define a generic function that's *constrained* to `where Element == SomeType<T>?`:

```
extension Collection {
    func values<T>() -> [T?] where Element == SomeType<T>? {
        return map( { $0?.value })
    }
}
```

This works:

```
let arr: [SomeType<Int>?] = [SomeType(value: 123), SomeType(value: 456)]
arr.values() // [Optional(123), Optional(456)]
```

You'll notice that I used a `func` instead of a computed property. I couldn't get the generic syntax right. Isn't this supposed to work?

```
extension Collection {
    // error: consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
    var values<T>: [T?] where Element == SomeType<T>? {
        return self.map( { $0?.value })
    }
}
```

Comment: That is elegant!

Comment: This is brilliant and certainly the most elegant, thank you for taking the time to reply. (See my edit in my original post for a fully realized implementation of this.) I accepted Martin's answer although it's not quite as elegant, it still allows the use of computed properties and has the bonus of showing inferred type in Swift's Quick Help instead of [T] / [T?].

Comment: Doesn't compile