# Swift convert [T?] to [T]?

Tags: swift

Is this a clean way to convert a list of `T?`'s to an optional list of `T`? (i.e., `[T?]` to `[T]?`) If a `nil` value is found, `nil` instead of T, otherwise output the normal list with no `Optional`.

For example:

```swift
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x.someMethod()  // [1, 2, 3, 4]

let y = [1, 2, nil, 3, 4]
y.someMethod()  // nil
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fast solution:

```swift
extension Array {
    func liftNil<T>() -> [T]? where Element == Optional<T> {
        if (allSatisfy {$0 != nil}) {
            return map { $0! }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

It checks if all the elements are not nil, then force-unwraps them if they aren't.

Usage:

```swift
let x: [Int?] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(x.liftNil())  // prints [1, 2, 3, 4]

let y = [1, 2, nil, 3, 4]
print(y.liftNil())  // prints nil
```

Benchmarks:

```
name          time           std        iterations
--------------------------------------------------

all satisfy 0      147.000 ns ± 2031.47 %    1000000
all satisfy 1   247828.000 ns ±  22.01 %        5328
all satisfy 2   124486.000 ns ±  39.23 %       10274
all satisfy 3  1065633.500 ns ±  21.17 %        1158

exceptions 0     51785.000 ns ± 439.14 %       24331
exceptions 1    798534.500 ns ±  19.08 %        1600
exceptions 2    423202.000 ns ±  68.97 %        2978
exceptions 3    807380.500 ns ±  31.74 %        1632

prefix 0           174.000 ns ± 665.61 %     1000000
prefix 1        276945.000 ns ±  16.10 %        4402
prefix 2        139071.000 ns ±  21.79 %        8968
prefix 3      14788294.000 ns ±  17.71 %         102

loop 0            2520.000 ns ± 1559.85 %     535007
loop 1         1645015.000 ns ±  80.56 %         823
loop 2          861541.000 ns ±  27.66 %        1298
loop 3         1594589.500 ns ±  17.97 %         798

cast 0           55364.000 ns ± 204.48 %       22089
cast 1        14288104.500 ns ±  16.70 %          92
cast 2         8464850.000 ns ± 216.15 %         188
cast 3        14432597.000 ns ±  32.76 %         100

compact map 0  1653247.500 ns ±  25.78 %         696
compact map 1  1618238.500 ns ±  25.45 %         740
compact map 2  1685990.000 ns ±  20.90 %         649
compact map 3  1604636.000 ns ±  20.45 %         805
```

Test cases:

```swift
// 0: nil at front
var arrTest0 = [Int?](repeating: 0, count: 5000)
arrTest1[0] = nil

// 1: nil at end
var arrTest1 = [Int?](repeating: 0, count: 5000)
arrTest2[4999] = nil

// 2: nil in middle
var arrTest2 = [Int?](repeating: 0, count: 5000)
arrTest3[2500] = nil

// 3: no nils at all
var arrTest3 = [Int?](repeating: 0, count: 5000)
```

As you can see, my solution using `allSatisfy` quite fast. Note that Martin R's "*just for fun solution*" using exceptions is very fast in the test case without nils. There seems to be no "clear winner", but only tradeoffs between performance in different cases.

I benchmarked everything using google's [`swift-benchmark`](https://github.com/google/swift-benchmark). The benchmark code can be found [on this github gist](https://gist.github.com/MonliH/a308c58c1e954284e0ff1699b9958768).

Also note, it would be worth benchmarking arrays with more than one `nil`.

---

<s>This code isn't very elegant, but it's performant as it only really does (at most) 1 pass through the array. Is't also faster than Martin R's solution when there is a `nil` as it immediately returns:</s>

As the benchmarks show, this is actualy slower than my original solution. I think it's because of the overhead of the `.append` method.

```swift
extension Array {
    func liftNil<T>() -> [T]? where Element == Optional<T> {
        var new: [T] = []
        new.reserveCapacity(count)
        for item in self {
            if let value = item {
                new.append(value)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return new
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some benchmark in your answer?

Comment: There is no need to iterate over all elements with `allSatisfy`. Just finding one nil element is enough with `contains` or `first(where:` to "disqualify" an array as your non-nil result under your criteria.

Comment: @Kamil.S actually, there's no difference in performance because `allSatisfy` will short-circuit and return `false` when it sees one `false` value. Under the hood, `allSatisfy` [uses `contains`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L540). I opted to use `allSatisfy`, but `contains` could work too.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply conditionally cast `[T?]` to `[T]`, this succeeds exactly if the array contains no nil elements:

```
let x: [Int?] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(x as? [Int]) // Optional([1, 2, 3, 4])

let y: [Int?] = [1, 2, nil, 3, 4]
print(y as? [Int]) // nil
```

As an extension method of `Array` that would be

```
extension Array {
    func someFunction<T>() -> [T]? where Element == Optional<T> {
        return self as? [T]
    }
}
```

---

*Previous, more complicated solutions:*
You can use `compactMap()` to get the non-nil elements, and then check if that is the same number as the original number of elements:

```
extension Array {
    func someFunction<T>() -> [T]? where Element == Optional<T> {
        let nonNils = compactMap { $0 }
        return nonNils.count == count ? nonNils : nil
    }
    
}
```

(The approach from [Swift: Extension on [<SomeType<T>?] to produce [<T>?] possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999688/swift-extension-on-sometypet-to-produce-t-possible/51001112#51001112) is used here to define an extension method for arrays of optional elements.)

Examples:

```
let x: [Int?] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(x.someFunction()) // Optional([1, 2, 3, 4])

let y = [1, 2, nil, 3, 4]
print(y.someFunction()) // nil
```

An alternative, just for fun: If you define an “unwrap or throw” method for optionals

```
extension Optional {
    struct FoundNilError : Error { }
    
    func unwrapOrThrow() throws -> Wrapped {
        switch self {
        case .some(let wrapped) : return wrapped
        case .none: throw FoundNilError()
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use that with  `map` and the “optional try”:

```
extension Array {
    func someFunction<T>() -> [T]? where Element == Optional<T> {
        try? map { try $0.unwrapOrThrow() }
    }
}
```

As soon as a nil element is found, `map` throws an error, and `try?` returns `nil`.

Comment: Funnily enough, my benchmarks show that the "just for fun" solution is actualy quite fast when there are no nils :)

Comment: @Monolith: I have added another, very simple method, perhaps you can benchmark that as well. (It is so simple that one would not really need to implement it as a method.)

Comment: Yes, I just added it! I do agree that the casting solution is probably the cleanest, though it's performance still isn't good as some of the other answers.

Comment: @Monolith just add an early exit in case nil is found `guard !contains(where: {$0 == nil}) else { return nil }`

Comment: Swift functions do not have "orThrow" in their names. That is Hungarian suffix notation, from a time before option-clicking. The labeling belongs on the argument. `orThrow error: @autoclosure () -> Error = FoundNilError()`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. What I am mainly suggesting is the optional cast to `[T]`, everything else is just ideas of what is possible. One can surely choose a better name than `unwrapOrThrow` (and you wouldn't call a method `someFunction` either). Btw, the labeling is not always on the argument, it is e.g. `replaceSubrange(_:with:)` and not `replace(subrange:with:)`. – Regarding your suggestion: I am not sure if it is better to introduce an argument just to put a label on it. And such a method would be called using the default argument as `unwrap()`, which *I* find unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Answer does requires at least **Swift 5.3**

Based on https://forums.swift.org/t/generic-function-that-requires-the-generic-type-to-be-non-optional/30936/11 I came up with:

```
extension Array {
    @inlinable
    public func someMethod() -> [Any]? {
        first {
            if case Optional<Any>.none = $0 as Any {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } != nil ? nil : map {
            if case Optional<Any>.some(let unwrapedValue) = $0 as Any {
                return unwrapedValue
            } else {
                return $0
            }
        }
    }
}

let x: [Int?] = [1,2,3,4]
let y = [1, 2, nil, 3, 4]
let z = [1,2,3,4]

print(x.someMethod())
print(y.someMethod())
print(z.someMethod())
```

Notice it does not require typing `[Int?]`  for the `z` case.

Output:

```
Optional([1, 2, 3, 4])
nil
Optional([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Unfortunately I am not able to pull off a `where` clause which would only apply to `nonoptional T`. It seems to be possible the other round only for `where Element == T?` as seen on the examples here. Which prevents me from proper typing to `[T]` and resorting to `[Any]`.

It's fairly easy for `x` & `y` with `public func someMethod<T>() -> [T]? where Element == T?` . But any attempt at generalizing this for nonoptionals seem to work as a blanket term as a result the `public func someMethod<T>() -> [T]? where Element == T?` case no longer gets called.

**Update** Small improvement over aforementioned problem which provides exact typing and less processing for the `z` case:

```
extension Array {
    @inlinable
    public func someMethod() -> [Element]? {
        return self
    }
    
    @inlinable
    public func someMethod() -> [Any]? where Element: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
        first {
            if case Optional<Any>.none = $0 as Any {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } != nil ? nil : map {
            if case Optional<Any>.some(let unwrapedValue) = $0 as Any {
                return unwrapedValue
            } else {
                return $0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

CompactMap can be used to drop the nils, then just see if the count is the same.

```
extension Array {
   func allOrNone<T>() -> [T]? where Element == Optional<T>   {
      let array = compactMap{$0}
      return array.count == count ? array : nil
   }
}
```

Comment: A pile of other similar answers were posted slightly quicker.  Give them any kudos!