# How can I remove all nil elements in a Swift array?

Tags: ios, swift

Basic way doesn't work.

```
for index in 0 ..< list.count {
    if list[index] == nil {
        list.removeAtIndex(index) //this will cause array index out of range
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: shortcut unwrapping of array of optionals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589605/swift-shortcut-unwrapping-of-array-of-optionals)

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `0 ..< list.count` is executed once at the beginning of the loop, when `list` still has all of its elements. Each time you remove one element, `list.count` is decremented, but the iteration range is not modified. You end up reading too far.

In Swift 4.1 and above, you can use [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) to discard the `nil` elements of a sequence. `compactMap` returns an array of non-optional values.

```
let list: [Foo?] = ...
let nonNilElements = list.compactMap { $0 }
```

If you still want an array of optionals, you can use `filter` to remove `nil` elements:

```
list = list.filter { $0 != nil }
```

Answer (score 76):

In Swift 2.0 you can use flatMap:

```
list.flatMap { $0 }
```

Comment: This also has the added benefit of not requiring the objects in the list to be Equatable.

Comment: Now that we have it, this is a better solution.

Comment: Relying on `flatMap { $0 }` to remove nils can lead to bugs. Use an [extension method like `removeNils()` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38548106/35690).

Answer (score 48):

Now in swift 4.2 you can use

```
list.compactMap{ $0 }
```

`list.flatMap{ $0 }` is already deprecated.

Comment: flatMap is not deprecated, rather it has a different use case now

Answer (score 2):

A much elegant solution would be to use `compacted()` defined in the Algorithms package made by Apple itself.

```swift
import Algorithms

let array = [10, nil, 20, nil, 30]
print(array.compacted()) // prints [10, 20, 30]
```

#### Benefits

1. Concise
2. Filters out nil items lazily

---

More info https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Compacted.md