# Swift split string by whitespace expect for text inside parentheses

Tags: swift

If i have a string something like: `"Hello world (this is Sam)"` i need to get the following array: `["Hello world", "this is Sam"]` and the following `["Hello","World","this is Sam"]` What would be the best way to achieve this in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you still need this but you can try this.

```
let originalString = "Hello world (this is Sam) Hello world (this is Sam) (this is Sam) Hello world Hello world (this is Sam)"
let newArr = originalString.components(separatedBy: ["(", ")"])

var finalArr = [String]()

for (index, value) in newArr.enumerated() {

    if (index + 1) % 2 == 1 {
        finalArr.append(contentsOf: value.components(separatedBy: " ").filter { $0 != "" })
    }
    else {
        finalArr.append(value)
    }
}

print(finalArr) //["Hello", "world", "this is Sam", "Hello", "world", "this is Sam", "this is Sam", "Hello", "world", "Hello", "world", "this is Sam"]
```

Comment: Thank you, this covers both my requirements and it's super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the first case, you could just split the string using parentheses as separators. Then, `omittingEmptySubsequences` will remove any empty string that goes into the split. Finally, trim any whitespaces or new lines that were left on any of the splitted elements.

```
let splittedText = text.split(omittingEmptySubsequences: true) { separator in
                       return separator == "(" || separator == ")"
                   }.map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer both seem to achieve the same thing, would you also regard my comment above about getting a result like ["Hello","World","this is Sam"]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can achieve that:

```
let originalString = "Hello world (this is Sam)"
let newArr = originalString.components(separatedBy: ["(", ")"]).filter { $0 != "" }
print(newArr) //["Hello world ", "this is Sam"]
```

I have mixed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571570/how-can-i-remove-all-nil-elements-in-a-swift-array) post to achieve it.

Comment: You should also avoid whitespaces when splitting, as it is shown in the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works.Also what would it be required to split it like this : ["Hello","World","this is Sam"]

Comment: You can do that by taking first object from the above result array and again split it with space like `separatedBy: [" "]`

Comment: What if the array had more text ? That would still just separate the first object in the array

Comment: What is your exact requirement because what you have asked in question is different than what you are discussing here

Comment: Turns out i need both and now i know how to achieve one of the desired results. If i also want to split the string string like "Some long string (don't separate this) some more text" i would need it to be split like the following:["Some","long","string","don't separate this","some","more","text"]

Comment: You should mentioned all your requirement from start in your question. Please update your question with your requirements. Thanks.