# Extract string array from string based on regex? - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, regex, string

So what I am trying to achieve:

I have an input string that looks like this:

```
let inputString = "1*1 (10, 10) (5, 5)"
```

Note the **space** after the first digit within the brackets.

To separate this input, I am using:

```
inputString.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

Which returns the following array:

**0:** `1*1`

**1** `"(10,"`

**2** `"10)"`

**3** `"(5,"`

**4:** `"5)"`

Where as the result I want is:

**0:** `"1*1"`

**1:** `"(10, 10)"`

**2:** `"(5, 5)"`

The issue is that the **space** within the coordinate is causing the string to separate again, when I don't want it to.

I have also tried to separate them using:

```
inputString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "\"([{)")).filter({ $0 != "" })
```

But this removes the **"("** and **")"** from the strings, which I need to **keep**.

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47985411/3832970. Just replace the `else` with `else {      finalArr.append("(\(value))")`

Answer (score 0):

**Without regex**

You can split with `(` and `)` and get odd chunks back while wrapping them with parentheses. You may re-use the code from :

```swift
let inputString = "1*1 (10, 10) (5, 5)"
let newArr = inputString.components(separatedBy: ["(", ")"])

var finalArr = [String]()

for (index, value) in newArr.enumerated() {

    if (index + 1) % 2 == 1 {
        finalArr.append(contentsOf: value.components(separatedBy: " ").filter { $0 != "" })
    }
    else {
        finalArr.append("(\(value))")
    }
}
print(finalArr)
// => ["1*1", "(10, 10)", "(5, 5)"]
```

**With regex**

You can match one or more occurrences of any substring inside parentheses or any char other than whitespace and parentheses:

```swift
import Foundation

func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
  do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range(at: 0), in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
let originalString = "1*1 (10, 10) (5, 5)"
print(matches(for: #"(?:\([^()]*\)|[^()\s])+"#, in: originalString))
// => ["1*1", "(10, 10)", "(5, 5)"]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vu8Mgb/1). *Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `[^()]*`  - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `|` - or

  - `[^()\s]` - any char other than `(`, `)` and whitespace
- `)+` - end of the group, one or more occurrences.

Comment: The matches function [looks familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/1187415) :)

Comment: @MartinR Very possible, I save good snippets and re-use them to showcase regular expression work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Which solution would you say is the best / cleanest to achieve what I am looking for? Either the first comment you posted or the matches function? Thanks!

Comment: @Liam I did not benchmark but I believe a non-regex solution would be faster.