# swift - How to print [String?] without the Optional statment

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

`let arr = ["foo", "bar", nil, "baz"]`

when I print it I get:

`print(arr) // [Optional("foo"), Optional("bar"), nil, Optional("baz")]`

However I'm looking to get an output that looks like:

`print(arr) // ["foo", "bar", nil, "baz"]`

I'm new to Swift's type system and the idea of downcasting and optionals. I know Optionals can be unwrapped using the `!` operator or `let x = arr.first {...}` but I'm not sur how to get the result I'm looking for or if it's even possible.

Comment: Remove the `nil` value from your array. Presence of `nil` value in your array makes the array optional.

Comment: Also related: [Swift: shortcut unwrapping of array of optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25589605/2415822)

Comment: On the contrary, it is not a blatant dupe of any of them. None of them provides a way to do what this question asks: print the strings as strings (with quotes and without `Optional(...)`) while printing the nils as `nil` (without quotes).

Comment: The answer, by the way, is `print(arr.map({ $0 ?? (nil as String? as Any) }))`.

Comment: That's interesting. How does the `nil as String? as Any` type casting work?