# How to flatten optional array of heterogenous values

Tags: swift

I have a heterogenous array that looks like this:

```
let array: [Any] = [
    [1, 2, nil],
    3
]
```

I'd like to flatten this to be an array [1, 2, 3]. How can I do this? Can I use `compactMap { $0 }` somehow?

Comment: Seems your question was already asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589605/swift-shortcut-unwrapping-of-array-of-optionals => yes, you, can use `compactMap`

Comment: @Vinzzz That's not a heterogenous array though, I've updated my code to make it clearer.

Comment: Then look at the recursive answer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-a-array-of-arrays-in-swift, I doubt any Swift standard operator helps you

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544741/2303865

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten \[Any\] Array Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544675/flatten-any-array-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension Collection {
    func flatMapped<T>(with type: T.Type? = nil) -> [T] {
        return flatMap { ($0 as? [Any])?.flatMapped() ?? ($0 as? T).map { [$0] } ?? [] }
    }
}
```

---

```
let array: [Any] = [[1, 2, nil],3]
// Use the syntax of your choice
let flattened1: [Int] = array.flatMapped()         //  [1, 2, 3]
let flattened2 = array.flatMapped(with: Int.self)  //  [1, 2, 3] 
let flattened3 = array.flatMapped() as [Int]       //  [1, 2, 3]
```